# Find functions following this constraint

Tags: functions, definite-integrals

> The numbers of possible continuous $f(x)$ defiend on $[0,1]$ for which $I_1=\int_0^1 f(x)dx = 1,~I_2=\int_0^1 xf(x)dx = a,~I_3=\int_0^1 x^2f(x)dx = a^2 $ is/are
>
> $(\text{A})~~1~~~(\text{B})~~2~~(\text{C})~~\infty~~(\text{D})~~0$
>
> I have tried the following:
> Applying ILATE (the multiplication rule for integration) - nothing useful comes up, only further complications like the primitive of the primitive of f(x). No use of the given information either.
> Using the rule $$ \int_a^b g(x)dx = \int_a^b g(a+b-x)dx$$
> I solved all three constraints to get
> $$ \int_0^1 x^2f(1-x)dx = (a-1)^2 \\
> \text{or} \int_0^1 x^2[f(1-x)+f(x)]dx = (a-1)^2 +a^2 \\$$
> Then I did the following - if f(x) + f(1-x) is constant, solve with the constraints to find possible solutions. Basically I was looking for any solutions where the function also follows the rule that f(x) + f(1-x) is constant.
> Solving with the other constraints, I obtained that f(x) will only follow all four constraints if the constant [= f(x) + f(1-x)] is 2, and a is $\frac{√3\pm1}{2}$.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your attempts at this problem.

Comment: I have tried using the multiplication rule for integrals to try and reach a point where I can use the given information, but have not succeeded.

Comment: Can you update the question with what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Apply Integration by parts on $I_2$, you will get

\begin{equation}
a = x-1
\end{equation}

Also apply Integration by parts on $I_3$, you will get

\begin{equation}
a^2 = x^2 - 1
\end{equation}

Above two equation satisfy only when $x=1$ and $a=0$

If you put these values in $I_2$, you will get

\begin{equation}
I_2 = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx = 0
\end{equation}
which contradict with $I_1$ so There is no such function.
Ans is (D) $0$.

Comment: Not possible. We apply the limits after integration, so x cannot remain.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is via statistics. You're counting [pdfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) on $[0,\,1]$ of [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) $0$. A $0$-variance variable is constant. Since the [Dirac Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta) is disqualified for not being a function, zero functions succeed.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean. Could you attach links to these topics? I have not heard of these.

Comment: @Green05 I've done that.